# using strlen in php for form validation

Tags: php, string, validation, strlen

I have the following validation:

```
    if (empty($errors) === true) { 
        if (strlen($_POST['Description']) > 250) { //strlen counts the number of bytes
            $errors[] = 'Your description must be less than 250 characters long';
        }
    }
```

But if a user puts in a description more than 30 characters long this error will always be displayed. I have read that strlen returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string. I have tried mb_strlen to get character length but this doesn't work either. I feel like i am doing something obviously stupid, please help if you can.

Comment: What is the input language? Have you tried mb_stren?

Comment: From php.net/mb_strlen If you find yourself without the mb string functions and can't easily change it, a quick hack replacement for mb_strlen for utf8 characters is to use a a PCRE regex with utf8 turned on.

$strlen = preg_match_all("/.{1}/us",$utf8string,$dummy);

This is basically an ugly hack which counts all single character matches, and I'd expect it to be painfully slow on large strings.

Comment: Try this http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/work-out-size-bytes-php-string-248.html

Answer (score 0):

Honestly i do not know of any encoding using 8 bytes for a character.

I think you "$_POST['Description']" may not contain only the data you want.

Do a

```
 var_dump($_POST['Description'])
```

And see what it shows.

on a sidenote:

```
if (strlen(trim($_POST['Description'])) > 250)
```

prevents whitespace to cause validation to fail.

Also note that you will have to specify the encoding to mb_strlen as the encoding of characters sent might not be the same as internal encoding.

Comment: When I do `var_dump($_POST['Description'])` i get the description that was posted and at the end it says `(length=1584)`...

Comment: and when you put <pre></pre> tags around it, do you see something weird or is it still ok?